how to use bool type with sqlc
I'm learning to use sqlc (with pgx)
my sqlc.yaml
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "query.sql"
    schema: "schema.sql"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "database"
        out: "../../pkg/database"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"


schema.sql

CREATE TABLE users (
  ulid varchar(26) PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  superuser boolean DEFAULT false,
  UNIQUE (email)
);

query.sql
-- name: CreateUser :one
INSERT INTO users (email, password, name, ulid, superuser) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *;


generated go code
type CreateUserParams struct {
    Email     string
    Password  string
    Name      string
    Ulid      string
    Superuser pgtype.Bool
}

func (q *Queries) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, arg CreateUserParams) (User, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRow(ctx, createUser,
        arg.Email,
        arg.Password,
        arg.Name,
        arg.Ulid,
        arg.Superuser,
    )
    var i User
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.Ulid,
        &i.Email,
        &i.Password,
        &i.Name,
        &i.Superuser,
    )
    return i, err
}


I try to implement with
func CreateUser(ctx context.Context, email, password, name string, superuser bool) (database.User, error) {
    conn, err := MakeDbConn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return database.User{}, err
    }
    defer conn.Close(ctx)

    queries := database.New(conn)

    hashedPassword, err := utils.HashPassword(password)
    if err != nil {
        return database.User{}, err
    }

    user, err := queries.CreateUser(ctx, database.CreateUserParams{
        Email:     email,
        Password:  hashedPassword,
        Name:      name,
        Ulid:      utils.MakeUlid(),
        Superuser: superuser,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return database.User{}, err
    }

    fmt.Println("new user: ", user)
    return user, nil
}


but vscode said: "cannot use superuser (variable of type bool) as pgtype.Bool value in struct literal" for that CreateUserParams.Superuser
Kindly please tell me how to user bool in sqlc properly
edit:
Got help from @gavin and @brits, i change the code to


    user, err := queries.CreateUser(ctx, database.CreateUserParams{
        Email:     email,
        Password:  hashedPassword,
        Name:      name,
        Ulid:      utils.MakeUlid(),
        Superuser: pgtype.Bool{Bool: superuser, Valid: true},
    })


And it solve

The error is saying a bool can't be used as a pgtype.Bool i.e. you need to provide a pgtype.Bool. Looking at the docs, you probably want Superuser: pgtype.Bool{Value: superuser, Status: pgtype.Present}.

Further to the above - the reason SQLC is using pgtype.Bool is because the value may be NULL (superuser is defined without a NOT NULL). If you add NOT NULL and regenerate the code the type will change, alternatively I believe you can use $5::boolean to force the type (obviouslly these approaches only work if you wil never want to write a NULL).

Gavin and Brits thankyou for your help, it solve the problem. I edited the question to include solving part

A more handy but less safe alternative solution would be to map pgtype.Bool to go native bool in the sqlc yaml config (relevant docs):
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: postgresql
    queries: ...
    schema: ...
    gen:
      go:
        ...
        overrides:
          - db_type: bool
            go_type:
              import: ""
              type: bool
          - db_type: bool
            go_type:
              import: ""
              type: bool
              pointer: true
            nullable: true

Please note that here I am overriding both nullable and non-nullable bool. The superuser field is nullable in your case, so it will be represented as *bool in go.
Some more discussion about using pgtype types and overriding them in this StackOverflow thread.
